# jsPDF not working in IE<10 browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to convert the HTML into PDF format. I am using the 'jsPDF' plugin and it's working in all the browser except IE<10. I am getting 'jsPDF undefined' error in the console of IE8 and IE9. please help me to fix this...

Here is my js

```js
function demoFromHTML() { alert("inside demoFromHTML");
 var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
 for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {  
  if(i==0 || i == table.rows.length-1 || row.cells.length < 2 || row.className == "item category"){}else{ 
   var quantity=row.cells[1].childNodes[0].value;
   row.cells[1].innerHTML = quantity;
   var priceOne = row.cells[4].childNodes[0].value;
   row.cells[4].innerHTML = priceOne;
   var priceTwo = row.cells[5].childNodes[0].value;
   row.cells[5].innerHTML = priceTwo;
   var priceThree = row.cells[6].childNodes[0].value;
   row.cells[6].innerHTML = priceThree;
  }  
 }
 var total = document.getElementById('total').value;
 document.getElementById('grandTotal').innerHTML = total;
 

 var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter')

 // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
 // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
 , source = $('#mainContentWide')[0]

 // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
 // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
 // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
 // (class, of compound) at this time.
 , specialElementHandlers = {
  // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
  '#bypassme': function(element, renderer){
   // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
   return true
  }
 }

 margins = {
      top: 10,
      bottom: 10,
      left: 10,
      width: 522
    };
    // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
    // 'inches' in this case
    pdf.fromHTML(
     source // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
     , margins.left // x coord
     , margins.top // y coord
     , {
      'width': margins.width // max width of content on PDF
      , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
     },
     function (dispose){
   alert("inside dispose function");
          pdf.save('Software.pdf');
        },
  
     margins
    )  
 
 document.getElementById("buttonPDF").disabled = 'true'; 
}
```

Error is showing at var jsPDF=new..... line

Comment: I guess you need to use `html5shim` for it. You can use conditional comments for it.

Comment: html5shim?  Is this a plugin?

Comment: i tried with html5shim also... But no changes...